# Element-wise computation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

For each element in two arrays, I want to compute the Mean Square Error, which is

`sum((a - b)^2)) / num of rows`

For example, if I have

```
aa = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[0,0,0,0]])
bb = np.array([[1,2,3,0],[1,1,1,1]])
```

The MSE will become `(16 + 4) / 2 = 10`

I tried to compute this element-wise but didn't find a good way to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by efficiently, but this should work:

```
((aa-bb)**2).sum(axis=1).mean()
```

you're calculating a-b, squaring it, then summing each row separately, then averaging the sums.

Comment: diff = aa-bb … np.sum(np.einsum('ij,ij->ij', diff, diff))/2 … is extremely fast, especially for large arrays (even this one)